# Deployment of Cloud Function that handle write and updates events

Tags: python, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I want to create a cloud function on python that helps me to count the number of documents in a collection everytime an object of a collection is been created or deleted and I found an example of [Cloud Firestore Triggers](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/calling/cloud-firestore) but I have a problem with this part of the code databases/(default) what do I should write on default? I have tried project_id+".firebaseio.com" or just".firebaseio" but my function isn't called.  Thank you for your time.

```
gcloud functions deploy FUNCTION_NAME \
  --runtime RUNTIME \
  --trigger-event providers/cloud.firestore/eventTypes/document.write \
  --trigger-resource projects/YOUR_PROJECT_ID/databases/(default)/documents/messages/{pushId}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are deploying to Cloud Functions (vanilla) not Firebase Cloud Functions.

If you want to deploy to firebase you need to deploy using a command similar to:

`firebase deploy --only functions`

and refer to the [Firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/get-started) for Firebase Cloud Functions

Regarding the `default` value, I just did a quick test on my project and this was my output

[image]

From the result of my test, I can infer that you should keep the "(default) value as it is.

Comment: I am not using Fireabase Cloud Functions because it isn't available on python language that's why I'm using Cloud Functions

Comment: Since you have the flag "firebase" your question was confusing. Why are you calling the "firebaseio.com"?. Regarding the default value I just updated my answer. Can you please provide us with more context on what exactly are you trying to do? are you trying to trigger your function from Firebase Firestore or from Google Cloud Platform Firestore?

Comment: Sure @Chris32 and thank you for your time! I want to create a background function on google cloud that can handle firestore events as documents creation so I need to set a trigger resource by I don't know what should be set as default Becase ```  --trigger-resource projects/$PROJECT/databases/default/documents/Project/{title}``` I set this and my function is not called when I create or modify an object in project

Comment: I have the same as you but I need to user gcloud functions call FUNCTION to trigger my function. ```Function triggered by change to: projects/PROJECT_ID/databases/(default)/documents/Project/*.``` It is not called when I modify a document or create it in Project collection

Comment: Can you please share with us the code of your function?